# Ограничить количество определенных символов в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Я хоть и знаком с регулярками и знаю где находится справочная документация, но все же не получается.

Меня интересует как написать регулярку ограничивающую например количество пробелов в строке, причем таким образом что пробелы могу располагаться в любом месте строки. подряд и не подряд

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]{8,20}$/
```

Эта регулярка мне очень нравиться, но она не ограничивает количество пробелов. Строка может состоять вся из пробелов- это нужно пресекать. Я конечно понимаю что могу использовать trimLeft trimRight однако строка вида `a               b` пройдет через трим и все еще будет не приемлема.

Comment: Не думаю, что такое нормально возможно сделать, лучше постобработку строки после регулярки и методами строк проверить количество пробелов

Comment: `/^(?=.{8,20}$)\s*[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*\s*$/`?

Comment: @SeGvr, примите ответ, который вам с решением :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
^(?=.{8,20}$)\s*[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*\s*$
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Qirmw5/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=.{8,20}$)` - в строке должно быть от 8 до 20 символов, отличных от перевода строки (если текст многострочный, добавьте флаг `s`, `/^(?=.{8,20}$)\s*[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*\s*$/s`)
- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - одна и более букв ASCII
- `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*` - ноль и более повторов последовательности ноля и более пробельных символов, за которыми следует одна и более букв ASCII
- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: А почему тут при нескольких строках регулярка выделила всё (76 символов) https://regex101.com/r/ORNrs6/1?

Comment: @gil9red Тестируйте правильно - https://regex101.com/r/ORNrs6/2. `\s` находит все пробельные символы, включая переводы строки.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, тестовые данные по вашей ссылке остались такими же, но поменялась регулярка - вы в ней заменили \s на пробел. Странно, а почему \s не сработал?

Comment: @gil9red Потому что в реальной жизни те строки - отдельные тексты, а в тесте - это один многострочный текст. Если хотите, замените `\s` на `[^\S\n]` (чтобы не находить переводы на новую строку).

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. А почему ограничение в 20 символов не сработало? :)

Comment: @gil9red Оно сработало: в первой строке от 8 до 20 символов. Флаг `m` установлен ведь.

Comment: Ага, если не проверять на тексте с несколькими строками, но работает. Спасибо за пояснения :)

Answer (score 0):

Строка от 8 до 20 символов, в которой от 2 до 4 пробелов, при этом пробелы расположены внутри строки:

```
/^(?=\S)(?=(\S*\s){2,4}\S+$)[a-z\s]{8,20}$/i
```

Comment: отсутствие описания делает ответ особенно полезным.

Comment: Попробовал регулярку и она ничего не нашла: https://regex101.com/r/NlpDx9/1

Comment: @gil9red, так ни одна твоя строка не соответствует условиям. Нужда строка от 8 до 20 символов, в которой от 2 до 4 пробелов, при этом пробелы расположены внутри строки.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение :) Значит, `(\S*\s){2,4}` ограничивало количество количество пробелов... Действительно, не хватает пояснения к регулярке :)

Comment: @gil9red, дописал в ответ.